# POSTing and rerouting a file through Flask

Tags: python, web-services, http, curl, flask

I'm currently running a Flask-RESTful application and an Apache Tika server in separate Docker containers. The Flask server is serving on port 5000 in both the container and host, and the Tika server at 9998.

I want to be able to pass a file uploaded to the Flask server by a client through to the Tika server so that I can extract the text of the document. However, I can't seem to get anything to work; every way I've tried of reading in the file has failed. Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

The following works in Python for accessing the Tika server:

```
requests.request('PUT', 'http://localhost:9998/rmeta/text', data=open('test_doc.docx', 'rb'), headers={}).text
```

However, trying to route through the Flask server like so breaks:

```
requests.request('post', 'http://localhost:5000/index', files={'file': open('test_doc.docx', 'rb')}, headers={}).text
```

#### app/__init__.py

```
class Index(MethodView):
    def post(self):
        #Load in file
        parse = reqparse.RequestParser()
        parse.add_argument('file', type=werkzeug.datastructures.FileStorage, location='files')
        args = parse.parse_args()
        uploadedFile = args['file']
        filename = secure_filename(uploadedFile.filename)

        #Create temporary file
        tmpfile = TemporaryFile()
        tmpfile.write(uploadedFile.stream.read())

        #Extract text
        data = tika.extract_text(tmpfile)
        tmpfile.close()
        return data
```

#### app/tika/__init__.py

```
import json
import requests

class Tika:
    def __init__(self, endpoint):
        self.endpoint = endpoint

    def extract_text(self, filedata):
        response = requests.request('put', self.endpoint, data=filedata, headers={}).json()
        try:
            return response[0]["X-TIKA:content"]
        except:
            return "ERROR"
```

#### Traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/conda/envs/SDL/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1997, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/opt/conda/envs/SDL/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1985, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/opt/conda/envs/SDL/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 273, in error_router
    return original_handler(e)
  File "/opt/conda/envs/SDL/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1540, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/opt/conda/envs/SDL/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 32, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/opt/conda/envs/SDL/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/opt/conda/envs/SDL/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/opt/conda/envs/SDL/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 273, in error_router
    return original_handler(e)
  File "/opt/conda/envs/SDL/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/opt/conda/envs/SDL/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 32, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/opt/conda/envs/SDL/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/opt/conda/envs/SDL/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/opt/conda/envs/SDL/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 480, in wrapper
    resp = resource(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/envs/SDL/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/views.py", line 84, in view
    return self.dispatch_request(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/envs/SDL/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/views.py", line 149, in dispatch_request
    return meth(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/__init__.py", line 109, in post
    data = get_clean_text(tika.extract_text(tmpfile))
  File "/app/tika/__init__.py", line 16, in extract_text
    response = requests.request('put', self.endpoint, data=filedata, headers={}).json()
  File "/opt/conda/envs/SDL/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 885, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/envs/SDL/lib/python3.5/json/__init__.py", line 319, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/opt/conda/envs/SDL/lib/python3.5/json/decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/opt/conda/envs/SDL/lib/python3.5/json/decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

It's got to be something with how I'm attempting to pass the file to the server and decode it, but for the life of me I can't figure it out. Any and all help would be immensely appreciated.

Comment: Change this `response = requests.request('put', self.endpoint, data=filedata, headers={}).json()` to `response = requests.request('put', self.endpoint, data=filedata, headers={}).text` and print the return value. You are most probably getting an error in form of html response. You need to look into it

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that no data is being passed to `tika.extract_text()`. This is because `tmpfile.write(uploadedFile.stream.read())` writes the uploaded data to the temporary file after which the file pointer is positioned at the end of the file. This file handle is then passed to `tika.extract_text(tmpfile)`, however, because the file pointer is at the end of the file, any read will return an empty string, therefore nothing is being passed through to your tika server.

You can easily fix this by seeking to the start of the temporary file before handing it off to `tika.extract_text()`:

```
    #Create temporary file
    tmpfile = TemporaryFile()
    tmpfile.write(uploadedFile.stream.read())
    tmpfile.seek(0)    # reposition file pointer to the start of the file

    data = tika.extract_text(tmpfile)
```

---

In the code that you've posted it's not clear to me why you need to use a temporary file. You could simply pass the uploaded data directly to the tika server:

```
from flask import Flask, request
from flask.views import MethodView
from flask.json import jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

class Index(MethodView):
    def post(self):
        uploaded_file = request.files.get('file')
        if uploaded_file:
            data = tika.extract_text(uploaded_file)
        else:
            data = {'error': 'Missing upload file'}

        return jsonify(data)

app.add_url_rule('/', view_func=Index.as_view('/'))

app.run()
```